# Problem in emacs-chess when I am using unicode symbols

Tags: unicode, games

When I configured chess to use unicode, it's not rendering properly.
Below is the configuration I am using for chess

```
(setq chess-default-display 'chess-plain)
(setq chess-default-engine 'chess-gnuchess)
(setq chess-gnuchess-path "gnuchess")
(setq chess-plain-border-style [9484 9590 9488 9591 9591 9492 9590 9496])
(setq chess-plain-piece-chars
 '((75 . 9812)
   (81 . 9813)
   (82 . 9814)
   (66 . 9815)
   (78 . 9816)
   (80 . 9817)
   (107 . 9818)
   (113 . 9819)
   (114 . 9820)
   (98 . 9821)
   (110 . 9822)
   (112 . 9823)))
```

[image]

Comment: I guess you'll want to use a font where the other characters are the same width as your chess characters are.